# PHP Update query : Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

Need help.

I'm having hard time trying to update the database with PHP. It keeps on giving me "Unknown column in 'field list'" error. I have run the same command through PHPMyadmin and it is successfully updating the data.

**Below is the table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `uid`              int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `name`            text,
  `photo_localurl`  text,
  `birthday`        text,
  `nickname`        text,
  `height`          text,
  `lastupdate`      timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**if I insert with back-tick in column name**

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET `height` = '$height' WHERE uid = '$uid'";
```

i get this error

```
UPDATE user SET `height` = '6\' 2"/|!-!|/1.88 m' WHERE uid = '51' Unknown column 'height' in 'field list'
```

**if i insert without back-tick**

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET height = '$height' WHERE uid = '$uid'";
```

I get this error

```
UPDATE user SET height = '6\' 2"/|!-!|/1.88 m' WHERE uid = '51' Unknown column 'height' in 'field list'
```

**if I use single tick**

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET 'height' = $height WHERE uid = $uid";
```

I get this error

```
UPDATE user SET 'height' = 6\' 2"/|!-!|/1.88 m WHERE uid = 51 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''height' = 6\' 2"/|!-!|/1.88 m WHERE uid = 51' at line 1
```

Comment: Have you tried putting backticks around the tablename, `user`? It's not a reserved keyword in MySQL I think, but it is in some other SQL based systems, can't hurt to try anyway :)

Comment: Can you check that `show create table user;` is like your create table statement.

Comment: Im not creating table on runtime. I just showed that it is my table structure.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a height value could be `6'2"`. When you insert it into the query string (`$sql`), it ends up looking something like:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET height = '6'2"' WHERE uid = '8'";
```

You see how this messes up your string right? It's screwing up your quotes.

Try using PHP's [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET height = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($height) . "' WHERE uid = '$uid'";
```

Comment: `addslashes()` should never be used for this. Instead, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is the better solution (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). If magic quotes are on, `stripslashes()` should be called first before doing the mysql escape.

Comment: value for $height is already coming through mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: `echo $sql;` What do you get?

Comment: I think where the problem is. $height value is an array and implode function is used. $height = mysql_real_escape_string(implode("/|!-!|/", $height));  If I echo this out i get "6\' 2"/|!-!|/1.88 m" without implode its output is "Array ( [imperial] => 6' 2" [metric] => 1.88 m )".

Comment: If I hard code the value of height I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_real_escape_string

```
  $sql = "UPDATE `user`.`userit` SET `userit`.`height` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($height) . "' WHERE uid = '$uid'";
```

Comment: Sorry guys this was a mistake from myside. I never looked at what DB was used. Somebody has selected different DB and I though that I was working on actual DB. It has almost same structure except few fields are missing. 

I'm really very embarrassed after finding that. I think I need a break. Time to go for a beer.